# How to build input files to obtain vibrational and thermodynamic measurements using Quntum Espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I'm working with a SiPOCa structure and I've already done the SCF, NSCF, DOS, BANDS, CHARGE DENSITY, FTIR and RAMAN calculations. Now I would like to calculate the vibrational and thermodynamic measurements of this structure using DFT and Quantum Espresso. Can anyone explain to me how I create the input files to perform these new calculations? Or if anyone can point me to some study material so I can learn